# how to add a background image to a css class

Tags: html, css

I want to add a background image to a CSS class but it dosn't show up.

I've already tried to add height and width.

```html
<div class="landing1">
  <h2>The Lnad OF Programming</h2>
  <p>get involved</p>
</div>


<style>
  body,
  html {
    margin: 0;
    size: 100%;
  }
  
  .landing1 {
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(imgs/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
  }
</style>
```

the background image isn't show up.

Comment: Check image path is correct or not

Comment: it works perfect please check your path:https://jsfiddle.net/b7vj1ufa/

Comment: Your image path is not correct...   make them correct, your image will be show.

Comment: i double checked the image path, it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working. You are giving the image path wrong

```css
body , html{
margin:0;
size:100%;
}

.landing1{
margin:3px;
text-align:center;
background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/500/500);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position:center;
width:400px;
height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="landing1">
    <h2>The Lnad OF Programming</h2>
    <p>get involved</p>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to add that i tried to do that as well.

Comment: Quotes not needed

Comment: no, i tried to put the image in the same folder with the index.html file

Comment: well, it worked when i used (http://placekitten.com/500/500). but it still not showig when i try from a local file :(

Comment: try and use the full path of the image, not relative

Comment: how can i do that? its in a folder in the desktop.

Comment: right click > properties in general tab see location

Comment: it's using a backslash, and i got the same result.

Comment: use as it: `url(./imgs/bg.jpg)` if it doesn't work see in f12 what the  error is

Comment: @לבנימלכה , same result. the error    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
bg.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: it worked when i added 'url(../imgs/bg.jpg)' , thanks alot!